# How to write query to retrieve last update rows from SQLite/ MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a table `chat`.
The column are `"id", "sender", "message", "time", "sender_email"`.
Some chat history which inserted into `chat` like:

```
1 John hihi 10:45 john@email.com
2 John hihi 10:46 john@email.com
3 Peter hihi 10:47 peter@email.com
4 John hihi 10:48 john@email.com
5 John hihi 10:49 john@email.com
6 John hihi 10:50 john@email.com
7 Mary hihi 10:51 mary@email.com
8 John hihi 10:52 john@email.com
9 Peter hihi 10:53 peter@email.com
10 John hihi 10:54 john@email.com
```

I would like to get the last message from people who appeared in the table.
If there is one who appear in the table many time, just get his last message.
So the result I would like to get should be:

```
10 John hihi 10:54 john@email.com
9 Peter hihi 10:53 peter@email.com
7 Mary hihi 10:51 mary@email.com
```

Is it possible to do so??
So far, I just write a sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name from chat ORDER BY id DESC
```

But seems it cannot display what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to determine which messages are the last one for each user (I'm doing this by `time` but you could do it by `id` too if you know a higher value definitely equals a later message), then get that message's data:

```
SELECT chat.*
FROM chat
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(time) AS time, sender
    FROM chat
    GROUP BY sender
) lastMsg ON chat.time = lastMsg.time AND chat.sender = lastMsg.sender
```

This also assumes there are no ties for `time`. If this is possible you'll have to go by id instead:

```
SELECT chat.*
FROM chat
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(id) AS id
    FROM chat
    GROUP BY sender
) lastMsg ON chat.id = lastMsg.id
```

Comment: thanks. but can you explain what means by lastMsg ON chat.id = lastMsg.id

Comment: @jjLin It's a join with a subquery. The subquery is named `lastMsg` (I omitted the AS but you could put one there). The ON then specifies the join condition

Comment: need to add ORDER BY id DESC, otherwise the order is not correct

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, sender, message, time, sender_email FROM
    (SELECT * FROM chat ORDER BY time DESC) AS temp 
GROUP BY sender ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: You should not include columns in your `SELECT` that are not in your aggregate.